# how to update item value in Nativescript ObservableArray together with the UI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, nativescript

I'm trying to make a twitter like app for memes, with basic functions like posting, commenting and like count. Also note that I'm using firebase firestore as my database. i would like that every time the like count updates in the database, the observable array item value updates as well and be visible live in UI

snippet of **JS** file, this populates the listview with **15** posts

```
const MemeCollection = firestore.firestore().collection("memes");
const query = MemeCollection.orderBy("createdAt","desc");

function onLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = {posts: ObsArray};
  query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      var duplicate = 0;
      var post_id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.id));
      ObsArray.forEach((item) => {

       //checks if post is duplicate
        if (item.id === post_id){
          duplicate += 1
          console.log("Duplicate")
        } else {

        }
      });
      if (duplicate == 0) {
        firebase.getValue('/users/'+ JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data().uid)) +'/profpic')
      .then(result => global.profPic = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.value)))
      .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));

      console.log(profPic);
      console.log(parseInt(doc.data().likes));

        ObsArray.push({id: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.id)),"profPic": profPic, "fromWho": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data().fromWho)), "title": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data().title)), "myImage": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data().imgsrc)), "date": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data().date)), "likeCount": parseInt(doc.data().likes)});
        console.log(" NotDuplicate")
      };
    });
  });
}
```

and the **XML** file

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ posts }}" id="postlist" pullToRefresh="true" pullToRefreshInitiated="pullToRefreshInitiated" itemTap="itemTapped">
                <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                  <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" marginBottom="3" /> 
                </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>

                  <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate itemTap="itemTapped">
                    <StackLayout backgroundColor="white">
                      <GridLayout rows="50,auto, auto, auto" columns="auto, *, *,*" class="layout">
                        <image src="{{ profPic }}" class="prof-pic" rowSpan="2" col="0" />
                        <label text="{{ fromWho }}" class="info_fromWho" textWrap="true" row="0" col="1" colSpan="3" />
                        <label text="{{ date }}" class="info_date" textWrap="true" row="0" col="1" colSpan="3" />
                        <label text="{{ title }}" class="info info_advtitle" textWrap="true" row="1" col="1" colSpan="3" />
                        <!--<label text="{{ message }}" class="info info_advdesc" textWrap="true" row="2" col="1" />-->
                        <image id="adv-img" visibility="{{ visibility }}" ngIf ="myImage" src="{{ myImage }}" class="imgs" textWrap="true" row="2" col="1" colSpan="3" stretch="aspectFill" tap="ImageTap" />
                        <label text="&#xf0e5;" class="fa info clear-btn white" row="3" col="1" colSpan="1" />
                        <label text="0" class="fa like_count clear-btn white" row="3" col="1" colSpan="1" />
                        <label text="&#xf08a;" class="fa info clear-btn white" row="3" col="2" colSpan="1" tap="likeTap" meme_id="{{ id }}" />
                        <label text="{{ likeCount }}" class="fa like_count clear-btn white" row="3" col="2" colSpan="1" />
                      </GridLayout>
                      <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>

              </lv:RadListView>
```

I tried using this code inside the duplicate checker but doesn't seem to work:

```
MemeCollection.doc(post_id).onSnapshot(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
     item.likeCount = doc.data().likes;
     }
  })
```

is there any way I could possibly edit/update the likeCount item value in ObservableArray whenever there are changes in like count in the database and feed it live in UI?

Comment: First of all, Observable Array may be only used to add / remove items and bind the updates to UI. If you want to bind specific property of an item in ObservableArray, you should use Observable within Observable array. Also your calls to fetch data from Firestore are async and you are trying to update the object synchronously, try using await in for loop to make them synchronous.

Comment: how do I implement using an Observable within Observable array if given 
`var pageData = new observable.Observable();`
in `ObsArray.push({id: "1", "data1": "2"})`?

Comment: Just push instance of Observable inside ObservableArray instead of plain object.

Comment: Example ```new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray([
      observableModule.fromObject({ name: "Hello", tapped: false }),
      observableModule.fromObject({ name: "World", tapped: false })
    ])```